# silently use PHP/Javascript to get user's resolution

Tags: php, javascript

I was wondering if I can use PHP and Javascript to get the screen resolution from my users. Altho this is a simple thing, I was wondering if I can execute the JavaScript within a PHP statement and not output the Javascript code to the browser as HTML

I thought maybe putting it in an EOF block, but that didn't work, the output was the actual script haha.

I want to be able to populate a `$width` and `$height` within my PHP script and create a variable to look something like

`$resolution = 800x600`

I know I can place the javascript in the HTML page and then have a PHP block capture the javascript output, but I am using the Smarty template engine and have disabled the use of PHP within the templates for security reasons.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I don't want to use the resolution for any url manipulating but rather to store the information for my statistical reasons.

Comment: Javascript is evaluated at the client side, PHP at the server side. You can't use PHP to execute javascript code, the browser is responsible for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript to php variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084216/javascript-to-php-variable)

Comment: yes, but i also need a work around for the smarty engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think what you want is really possible.  It has to be in the HTML output for the browser to execute it.

You can capture it in the page JavaScript and use an AJAX call to POST it back to the server... but at that point you may as well use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), because I'm pretty sure that's essentially what they do (but their framework is supported by, well... Google).  Using Google Analytics will also prove to be useful, since they capture a number of other statistics as well.